# I try to connect my Expo app to localhost backend but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

My server is running on localhost:5000 and my iPhone is connected to metro server with tunnel method using Expo. I tried to change localhost with the ip address of my Pc but the log is the following:

```
Network request failed
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

the code of my fetch function is:

```
const onSubmitHandler = () => {
              const payload = {
                  phone,
                  name,
                  surname,
                  password,
                  city,
                  dateOfBirth,
              };
              fetch("http://192.168.1.40:5000/signup", {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
              })
              [....]
                      }
                  } catch (err) {
                      console.log(err);
                  };
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
              });
          };
```

and my index.js of server is:

```
import express from 'express';

import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

import sequelize from './utils/database.js';

import router from './routes/routes.js';

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());

app.use((_, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.use(router);

sequelize.sync(); 

app.listen(5000);
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Likely need to look into App Transport Security Settings, mobile apps normally default to blocking insecure network requests aka requests made over http. You're making a request to http:// 192.168.1.40:5000, either change that to localhost or add exception domains

Answer (score 0):

You can try using localtunnel.

Install by running:

```
npm i -g localtunnel
```

After installation run to create a `https` url for you:

```
lt --port 8000
```

Your result should look like:

```
your url is: https://kind-moments-train-197-210-226-136.loca.lt
```

Now you can use the url along with the port.
Example:

`https://kind-moments-train-197-210-226-136.loca.lt:5000/signup`

Answer (score 0):

**Add this in `app.json` of your file:**

```
{
          "expo": {
            "web": {
              "proxy": "http://<your_backend_ip>:<your_backend_port>"
            }
          }
        }
```